# Drawer footer items

Tags: flutter, footer, drawer, items

i have some little trouble with the drawer , i've searched on stack a solution for this , and found a solution , but after trying it out , it didnt work for me ! :) the idea is , i want  to have some items in drawers displayed in the very end of it ! :)

```
Drawer(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF0098c2)),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Dealer',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => dealerBuilder()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Shuffler',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.shuffle,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => shufflerBuilder()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Mistakes',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.info_outline,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => mistakePage()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Important links',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.border_color,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => importantLinks()));
            },
          ),
          Container(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Divider(),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                          title: Text('Facebook')),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                          title: Text('Instagram'))
                    ],
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

thats the code that i've got in my drawer , so far its displaying this way ! [image: thats the output , but i want to display it in the bottom]

Answer (score 12):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can replace `ListView` with `Column` and wrap first group with `Expaned Column`

```
 child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              ...
              Container(
                child: Align(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF0098c2)),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Dealer',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        /* Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => dealerBuilder()));*/
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Shuffler',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.shuffle,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        /*Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => shufflerBuilder()));*/
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Mistakes',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.info_outline,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        /* Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => mistakePage()));*/
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Important links',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.border_color,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        /*Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => importantLinks()));*/
                      },
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Divider(),
                            ListTile(
                                leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                                title: Text('Facebook')),
                            ListTile(
                                leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                                title: Text('Instagram'))
                          ],
                        ))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good but it is not fully responsive. Depending on the phone screen size and the number of `ListTile` you can get an overflow.

Comment: if we use `ListView` instead of `Column` inside `Expanded` then overlapping issue is resolved.
`Container(child: Column(children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: ListView(children: <Widget>[/* top widgets*/]),),Align(alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,child: Column(children: const <Widget>[/* bottom widgets*/]))]))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of doing it

**Code:**

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF0098c2)),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // your ListTile here
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              // your footer widgets here
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(),
);
```

By using `LayoutBuilder`, `ConstrainedBox` and `IntrinsicHeight` you are going to be able to use `Expanded` even inside a ScrollView and keep your image footer at the bottom. It ensure you to have a responsive layout on any phone screen.

**Result in image:**
[image]

**Full test code used**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF0098c2)),
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                    minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                    maxHeight: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ...List<Widget>.generate(
                                  5,
                                  (index) => ListTile(
                                        title: Text(
                                          "$index",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                        leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.person,
                                          size: 20,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                      )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  ListTile(
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                                    title: Text('Facebook'),
                                    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                  ),
                                  ListTile(
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                                    title: Text('Instagram'),
                                    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Drawer(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF0098c2)),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Dealer',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => dealerBuilder()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Shuffler',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.shuffle,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => shufflerBuilder()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Mistakes',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.info_outline,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => mistakePage()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Important links',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.border_color,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => importantLinks()));
            },
          ),
          Expanded(),
          Container(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Divider(),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                          title: Text('Facebook')),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                          title: Text('Instagram'))
                    ],
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: It won't work because Expanded try to take as much space as possible and ListView give it an infinite height.

Answer (score 0):

> Expanded on SizedBox works for me!

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            // SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: ProfileAvatar(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
            Text("Syed Tariq Ullah"),
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(onPressed: (){},
              icon:Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_arrow)),
                      ],
                
                    ),
                  ),
          ],)),
            
        SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2_fill),
          title: Text("Messages"),
        ),
           ListTile(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chart_bar),
          title: Text("Stats"),
        ),
           ListTile(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.briefcase),
          title: Text("Your Content"),
        ),
           ListTile(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bookmark),
          title: Text("Bookmarks"),
        ),
           ListTile(
          leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.doc_text),
          title: Text("Drafts"),
        ),
        Divider(height: 2.0,),
        
      
        Expanded(child: SizedBox(height: 20,)),
        
         Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           child: ListTile(leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.settings_solid),
           title: Text("Settings"),
           trailing: Icon(CupertinoIcons.ellipsis),
           ),
         ),
         // Spacer(),
         
      
      ],),
      
    
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scaffold. If you want a header that doesn't move, you can set appBar to a PreferredSize widget with the child as DrawerHeader or whatever you want. Set body to ListView for a scrollable list. And set bottomNavigationBar to Container with some height (say 144 for 3 buttons), then the child to a Column widget.

```
 return Drawer(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(144),
            child: DrawerHeader(child: Image.asset("")),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: const Text("dark mode"),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.dark_mode_rounded),
                trailing: Switch(
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text("metric"),
                leading: const Icon(Icons.thermostat_rounded),
                trailing: Switch(
                    value: true,
                    onChanged: (value) {}
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: 144,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Settings"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Help"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.help_outline_outlined),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Log Out"),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it under Drawer() widget

```
const Spacer(),
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
    child: TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: const Text('Logout'),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout)),
 ),
```

You can use a Center and Row widget in padding child to have multiple items shown at bottom in center, other than that spacer works perfectly fine to add vertical space and take the widgets to very bottom.

Answer (score -2):

hey I think I figured out the answer it might help -
you can use a spacer widget that occupies all the streched space spaces